# Randomly 'Login Timeout expired' in sql server via Excel ADODB

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, sql-server-2016, adodb

From Excel users are sending data to the SQL Server Database.
Now randomly users are receiving 'Login timeout expired' messages. I did not change much compared to last week. It fails on the connection step.

My generic connection code:

```vb
Public Function MyConn() As ADODB.Connection
'Make connection to the DB. Can be called from all macro's
On Error GoTo Message2
Static cnn As ADODB.Connection
Run "BP_Procedures.BP_setparameters"

   Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source= " & Data_source & _
                 "Initial Catalog= " & Initial_catalog & _
               "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
cnn.CursorLocation = adUseClient


Set MyConn = cnn
Exit Function

Message2:
noVPN = True
Exit Function


End Function
```

In the macro's that perform a DB command, I have the following code:

```vb
 'Make connection
Set cn = MyConn()
cn.CommandTimeout = 0

'insert new lines
insertsql = "INSERT INTO [tbl_Proc_Division_Prod] ([Prdl_ID],[Opp_ID],[Product],[Product_pct]) VALUES ('" & ws.Cells(r, 7) & "'," & ws.Cells(r, 8) & ",'" & ws.Cells(r, 9) & "'," & ws.Cells(r, 10) & ")"
cn.Execute (insertsql)

'Close connection to DB
 cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
Set cn = CloseConn()
```

The close connection vba:

```vb
Public Function CloseConn() As ADODB.Connection
'This macro is to close the connection to the DB. Can be called from all macro's
Static cnn As ADODB.Connection


Set cnn = Nothing
Set CloseConn = cnn

End Function
```

Also on SQL Server Level (Tools > Options > Query Execution), I have set the Query Execution time-out to 0. In SQL Server Management studio I see the database is fine and I can run queries on it.

What can I do more? What is the reason these time outs started?

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is *dangerous*; it is wide open to SQL Injection attacks. You *need* to fix the huge security flaw in your code. Learn from people's mistakes from the last couple of decades and secure your code.

Comment: How do you mean dangerous? I did not add the connection parameters in the script nor the insert items?

Comment: Just put `= "'); DELETE tbl_Proc_Division_Prod; --"` in a cell and watch the fireworks.

Comment: Haha yes ok, what do you advice? How to execute commands to the DB then? via stored procedures?

Comment: Rather than string concatenation to build queries you execute your queries with ADODB.Command objects and pass the tainted user data via [ADBODB.Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado). Besides solving the SQL Injection issue it also leads to more efficient queries due to plan caching and reuse in the SQL Server.

Comment: Ok thanks! I will look into this. So you are suggesting the issue would be more likely on the query side of Excel than on SQL Server?

Comment: It is, in truth, unlikely the the injection issue is related to the time out; unless you're sending malformed queries (due to the injection, such a value with a single quote(`'`) in its value) instead and that's causing some kind of odd time out issue. Though that does not diminishing the urgency to resolve said security issue.

Comment: Users are entering data in one sheet. In another sheet I am formatting the data for the upload, adding quotes for textfields and validating inputs. But indeed I need to focus on improving this point too. Hopefully somebody can help me a bit on the timeout side.